# Response time increasing with time Spring-Boot application?

Tags: python, java, django, postgresql, spring-boot

I am a beginner in Backend development. So, in case I haven't mentioned my problem correctly or you want more information around the problem, please ask, I will learn.

We have our backend in Python-Django monolithic architecture, which we are planning to shift to Spring-boot micro-services. The database we are using is Postgres.

I started it by shifting the critical `GET` APIs first of our existing code, i.e. `POST` and `PATCH` requests are handled by the Django application independently, but the `GET` requests are handled by Spring-Boot.
So, I have re-routed the `GET` API call on Python-Django to Spring boot microservice, using *Requests HTTP Library* and added a fall back again to Python-Django code if the **requests.status_code is not 200** from Spring-Boot Application

Python Rerouting code snippet:

```
SPRING_URL = SPRING_MICROSERVICE_URL + "/users/sent/{user_id}/"
response = requests.get(
   url=SPRING_URL.format(user_id=self.request.user.id), params=payload
)
if response.status_code == 200:
    return self.get_response(data=response.json())
else 
    fallback to the existing python-django code
```

There are 6-7 DB calls, out of which only 1 is time-consuming on a *Materialized View* PSQL, which takes around **1 sec** for some of the requests in my local and staging machines. I am using HikariCP for connection pooling.

Now, when I am testing it on my local machine and staging machine using **JMeter** **directly on the Spring-Application** it shows an average time of **90-100 ms with max-min being 30 and 2500 ms** respectively, and around **110-140 ms with min-max 50-3000 ms respectively** through django rerouting, which is acceptable.

**JMeter Thread Properties:**

```
Number of threads (users) : 2
Ramp-up period (seconds) : 1
Loop Count : 1000
```

Now, when I deploy it on **Production** (django http requests are rerouted to spring-boot) server, the response time goes on increasing with time, which I expected to decrease or at-least equals with django application.
Django application (without rerouting) took around 200-220 ms on **Production**, but now it increases with time from 31 ms to 10,000 ms and continues to increase (so we reverted back to django application)

One of the bottlenecks is the query to *psql-view*, for which I tried to increase connection pool size from the application as well as DB side, but it didn't work.

I have no idea, why is it behaving so badly in production, which I expected to improvise. Please suggest something.

**My questions**:

1. Is it a good practice to call Spring-boot application from Django application? As both handle multiple HTTP requests differently.
2. As spring applications can handle multiple requests using multiple threads, and django serves one request at one time, so does it play any role in the slowdown?
3. Does increasing connection pool size helps, in my case?

Some Configs :
Using `Gradle` as build-automation tool
Django - gunicorn.config - `threads = 4`

Comment: There are many variables here and it's a bit difficult to determine where the problem is.  To simplify I would try to not have the Django app act as a proxy.  It's unclear if it's because of threading or something else.  See where the bottlenecks are with that.  In general, increasing a connection pool size may help but unless you know for sure that the problem is connection contention it also may not do anything.

Comment: Hi,
Responding to your three questions:
1) In my opinion the best approach here is to use a gateway (for instance Spring Cloud Gateway) to route the requests to the correct place, instead of use this approach inside the oldest service;
2) Here to have responses you need data, so probably you need to sleuth + zipkin (or similar tools) to measure and observe the response times;
3) Try to use tools like VisualVM to analyze your code and try to spot the code areas with more memory consumption.